# Merge Excel worksheets into one

Tags: excel, ms-access, vbscript, worksheet-function

I have hundreds of different worksheets in a single workbook and I need to append (not sum) all the data from each worksheet onto the others and put it all in one huge master worksheet. All the column names are exactly the same for every worksheet.

My end goal here is to then take all the data from the master worksheet and put it into an Access database, so if anybody also knows an easy to way to grab data from hundreds of excel worksheets all at once and put it into a database that would be great.

It seems like the best way to do this is some sort of VBScript, but I am very unfamiliar with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBA more simply than VBScript:

```
   'Requires reference to the Microsoft Excel x.x Object Library

   Dim strFileName As String
   Dim objXL As New Excel.Application
   Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
   Dim wks As Object

   'objXL.Visible = True

   strFileName = "C:\Docs\LTD.xls"
   Set wkb = objXL.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)

   For Each wks In wkb.Worksheets
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
           "TableName", strFileName, True, wks.Name & "$"
   Next

   'Tidy up
   wkb.Close
   Set wkb = Nothing
   objXL.Quit
   Set objXL = Nothing
```

Transferspreadsheet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214134(v=office.12).aspx

Note that you may run into problems with long column names, reserved characters or names in column names, date data types, mixed data in columns and long data in columns.

Comment: Alright, just a couple questions here. Where do I put this code? I've noticed I can right click on a worksheet and click 'view code' and mess around with that, otherwise I'm sort of in the dark about where I should store and run this code you have given me.

Comment: Alright. So where do I store and run this code to populate an Access database with the desired information?

Comment: You can create a module in MS Access http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/database-basics-HA010064450.aspx and add a procedure into which you can paste the above code. You can then edit it to suit your set-up. It is not unlikely that you will run into conversion problems.

Comment: Alright, I created a module and added a procedure. How do I actually run this procedure?

Comment: You can click on "Sub" and choose Run from the toolbar, for one.

Comment: You will need to add a reference to the Excel library first, by choosing Tools->References and ticking the right box.